# How to make the boolean effect and animation when I render it out, but keep the boolean hidden

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, boolean-modifier

I try many things but somehow it still doesn't work, everything is okay in the camera view, but when I try to render it out the effect of the boolean dissaper
[image]

When I try to render it out the boolean effect is not there
[image]

Comment: In the _Outliner_ window on the top right, there are objects with disabled viewport visibility (the greyed-out eye symbol), but still visible for render (the camera symbol). If you want to make them invisible in render you have to disable the camera symbol as well.

Comment: I have disable the camera symbol, as u can see in the picture the camera symbol on the sphere is disable

Comment: When you show me where in your question I should have seen that from all the objects the sphere is the one in question, I could probably tell you why I gave you a useless answer...

Comment: not at all, thank you for answering, I think the problem is in the render setting probably, but somehow I cannot find it

Comment: I think I found out what's the problem, I deleted the modifier boolean first and try to apply it again, It worked somehow